# Specific to Firefox -- missing token ‘user-agent’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel

Tags: javascript, google-maps, firefox, cors

I'm trying to make a api call to googleMapsClient geocode and I'm getting a XHR error only when using firefox. It works fine in chrome but in firefox, I'm getting the following error

```
>     Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Kothaguda%2C%20Hyderabad%2C%20Telangana%2C%20India&key=xxxx.
> (Reason: missing token ‘user-agent’ in CORS header
> ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel)
```

Not sure why this is specific to Firefox. I can see that the there is a 'user-agent' http header in the request. Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Disable whatever Firefox extensions you have installed. Or remove the part of your frontend code that’s adding a custom User-Agent request header to the request.

Comment: I don't have any extensions installed on Firefox. Also, I'm not adding a custom User-Agent request header from the frontend code. Browser itself is adding User-Agent header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the `@google/maps` package? Please note that this package is supposed to be used with node.js only, not in the browser. This is also stated in the [README](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js#attention):

> Attention!
>   This library is designed for server-side Node.js applications. Attempting to use it client-side, in either the browser or any other environment like React Native, may in some cases work, but mostly will not. Please refrain from reporting issues with these environments when attempting to use them, since server-side Node.js applications is the only supported environment for this library. For other environments, try the Maps JavaScript API, which contains a comparable feauture set, and is explicitly intended for use with client-side JavaScript.

I suggest using the Google Maps JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

Just got done dealing with this exact same issue. I was using the `@google/maps` library and the geocoding worked fine in Chrome (v71) but the preflight failed in Firefox (v64) with the same error as the original question.

As suggested by Rob, I ended up moving to using the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to do the geocoding instead.

Looking at the details of each request... it appears that `@google/maps` npm package uses a different URL than the Google Maps JavaScript API. As a matter of fact... the URL used by the JavaScript API returns a JSONP structure and avoids dealing with the whole CORS thing all together.

It's still a mystery to me why using `@google/maps` to geocode an address worked fine in Chrome and not in Firefox. I assume Firefox has more strict CORS requirements when compared to Chrome.